# Rails - undefined method `api_key' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im trying to store my api key in a yaml file

fresh_desk.yml

```
production:
  :api_key: 12345

staging:
  :api_key: 12345

development:
  :api_key: my api key here
```

then in my lib folder i have a file called

fresh_desk_api_wrapper.rb

```
  class FreshDeskApiWrapper

  attr_accessor :config, :client

  def initialize
self.config = YAML.load("#{Rails.root}/config/fresh_desk.yml")[Rails.env]
self.client = Freshdesk.new("http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/", config.api_key, "X")
  end

  def post_tickets(params)
client.post_tickets(params)
  end
end
```

then in my

clients_controller.rb

```
def create
  FreshDeskApiWrapper.new().post_tickets(params[:client])
  redirect_to new_client_path
end
```

but when i submit my form i get an error

```
undefined method `api_key' for nil:NilClass
```

does anyone know whats causing this?  and how to fix it?

Comment: Json syntax is `a: b`, not `:a: b`

Answer (score 1):

you might need a File.open 
*blah.yml*

```
production:
  :api_key: 12345

staging:
  :api_key: 45678

development:
  :api_key: 10203
```

Then you can load it into a hash

```
>> require 'yaml'
=> true
>> config = YAML::load(File.open('blah.yml'))
=> {"production"=>{:api_key=>12345}, "staging"=>{:api_key=>45678}, "development"=>{:api_key=>10203}}
```